# How to correct the error in this sql code?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
select title
from Movie M , Rating R
where exists((select M.mID
               from Movie)
               except (select R.mID
                       from Rating));
```

> Error: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data along with expected output.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Do the proper `JOIN`s with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT m.* FROM Movie m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rating r
                  ON r.mID = m.mID 
WHERE r.mID IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks you a lot but there is no null for mid that's why i used except

Comment: @Amira Look up how [outer joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join) work.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are used for subqueries, but a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) is not composed of subqueries, so you must write both SELECTs together:

```
SELECT title
FROM Movie M , Rating R
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT M.mID
              FROM Movie
              EXCEPT
              SELECT R.mID
              FROM Rating);
```

But while this query is syntactically valid, it still does not make sense.
EXISTS just checks whether the subquery on the rights side return any rows; this usually requires a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) to make the subquery depend on the current row in the outer query. And it does not make sense to have the `Rating` table in the outer query.

You should use IN instead of EXISTS:

```
SELECT title
FROM Movie
WHERE mID IN (SELECT mID
              FROM Movie
              EXCEPT
              SELECT mID
              FROM Rating);
```

And you already know that all IDs in the `Movie` table exist in the `Movie` table, so you do not have to repeat it in the subquery; simply reverse the comparison:

```
SELECT title
FROM Movie
WHERE mID NOT IN (SELECT mID
                  FROM Rating);
```